# How to Connect and Send Data using bluetooth c# Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, xamarin

I already am able to find the devices and almost connect to them, im sure the connecting button is working but the other device is no answering right so its not connecting i need help with that...
And after they be connected i would need to send a zip file by bluetooth and i really dont have any idea how to do that.

Here is my code

http://pastebin.com/hwERjS6u

And here is the blueToothChatService class im using

http://pastebin.com/6SH56Wqj

If someone already made this or has any sample to help me i would be really thankful my brain is melting... -.-

Thanks

Comment: Could you update the question to include the code directly in the question instead of pastebin links?

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing some Bluetooth stuff on Xamarin Android recently and found the following source code incredibly helpful.

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/BluetoothChat/

Comment: I downloaded that too but i cant understand everything i dont even have a clue how to send a .zip as bytes

Comment: Have a look at the third option at http://evilzone.org/java/(android)-three-ways-to-send-data-over-bluetooth/

Comment: So after the devices are connected and pared all i need to do is run that function?

Comment: And as i want to just send a .zip file cant i use that intent? I want the simplest way

Answer (score 0):

...

[Android Connectivity](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814814/Android-Connectivity)

From someone that knows what they are doing - Nice Article: Peter Leow

```
BluetoothServerSocket  bluetoothServerSocket = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(getString(R.string.app_name), uuid);

private final static UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("fc5ffc49-00e3-4c8b-9cf1-6b72aad1001a");
```